# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'MediaLibrary.MediaType') React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, media-library

I'm getting the TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'MediaLibrary.MediaType')
when i'm using react-native-media-library library in react native.

Answer (score 0):

yes its have an media type issue, recently i have move on another library

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cameraroll@https://github.com/mirzahayat/react-native-cameraroll.git
```

git will give you album data with the help of getAlbum method ,
and get the media with album name,

e.g
type
/// SmartAlbum for ios
/// Album fro android

getAllAlbum(type) will help you get the Media

```
  const getAllAlbum = async (type: string) => {
  const data = await CameraRoll.getAlbums({
    assetType: 'All',
    albumType: IOS ? type : 'All',
  });
  const promises = data.map((elem: any) => {
    return getDataByAlbum(elem, type);
  });
  return await Promise.all(promises);
};

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      first: data.count,
      assetType: 'All',
      groupName: data.title,
      include: [
        'fileSize',
        'imageSize',
        'playableDuration',
        'location',
        'filename',
      ],
      groupTypes: IOS ? type : 'All',
    }).then(res => {
      const photos = res.edges;
      let groups: any = Array.from(
        new Set(photos.map(photo => photo.node.image)),
      ).map((item: any, index: any) => {
        const fileEx = item?.filename?.split('.').pop();
        return {
          ...item,
          type: extensionCheck(String(fileEx).toLowerCase()),
          uri: IOS
            ? `assets-library://asset/asset.${String(
                fileEx,
              ).toLowerCase()}?id=${item?.uri.slice(5, 41)}&ext=${String(
                fileEx,
              ).toLowerCase()}`
            : item.uri,
        };
      });
      return (
        groups && {
          title: data.title,
          count: data.count,
          data: groups,
        }
      );
    });
    resolve(result);
  });
};
```